# File System Watcher in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have created an application in vb.net that look into specific folder for picking up new files whenever they are dropped. But for some reason if there is no new file for 24 hours and then I drop a new file it doesn't trigger event.

Seems like file system watcher goes to sleep after sometime if there is no new file coming. Does anyone knows how to fix this issue ? Or does anyone has faced this issue ?

Comment: Going to need a lot more info.  What type of app have you got the FileSystemWatcher embed in?  I've had Windows services with FileSystemWatchers that have run flawlessly for months at a time

Comment: Windows form application using vb.net coding

Comment: And how is this window forms app running, something like a desktop shortcut the user is running, how exactly are you initializing the file system watcher.  Are your sure that it's not the app itself is crashing in some manner?  Show us some code

Comment: The application is running on server whenever we drop new file it process that file. But when there is no file e.g. during the weekend it stops working on Monday and we have to manually restart the application. We don't get any error file system watcher just stops identifying new files in the folder if it stays idle for some time.

Comment: Still would be helpful to show us some code, but perhaps its some power saving thing.  Maybe over the weekend the HDD is being put into a sleep mode and the file watcher is not able to recover from that.  Maybe the easy fix is to schedule the app to automatically restart periodically

Comment: Server doesn't go into sleep mode that's for sure. Is there a time frame for File System Watcher that if there is no file then it goes to sleep ?

Comment: There is no timeframe I've ever seen for the filsystemwatcher.  Like I've said, I've had it running for months with out problem